# How to hide files in eclipse plugin development?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to hide a physical file (eg: Sample.abc) which is generated at runtime.This should not be shown to the user.How can i programmatically handle this logic in my eclipse plugin development.

Thanks in advance

Regards
Mathan

Comment: Do you want to hide it in your eclipse workspace like the "bin" folder or do you want to hide it in your apllication based on eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to hide some files in your application based on eclipse, you can call

```
IFolder byteFolder; // Some folder
byteFolder.setTeamPrivateMember(true);
byteFolder.setDerived(true);
```

setDerived is a interface methode of [IResource](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResource.java.htm)

> A derived resource is a regular file
>   or folder that is created in the
>   course of translating, compiling,
>   copying, or otherwise processing other
>   files. Derived resources are not
>   original data, and can be recreated
>   from other resources. It is
>   commonplace to exclude derived
>   resources from version and
>   configuration management because they
>   would otherwise clutter the team
>   repository with version of these
>   ever-changing files as each user
>   regenerates them.
>
> If a resource or any of its ancestors
>   is marked as derived, a team provider
>   should assume that the resource is not
>   under version and configuration
>   management by default. That is, the
>   resource should only be stored in a
>   team repository if the user explicitly
>   indicates that this resource is worth
>   saving.
>
> Newly-created resources are not marked
>   as derived; rather, the mark must be
>   set explicitly using setDerived(true).
>   Derived marks are maintained in the
>   in-memory resource tree, and are
>   discarded when the resources are
>   deleted. Derived marks are saved to
>   disk when a project is closed, or when
>   the workspace is saved.
>
> Projects and the workspace root are
>   never considered derived; attempts to
>   mark them as derived are ignored.
>
> This operation does not result in a
>   resource change event, and does not
>   trigger autobuilds.

Comment: Hi Markus,
Thanks for your response, 
If iam setting "team private member"  and 'derived'  as 'true'.
Can i access files inside in this hidden folder ?
Can i write data in these files ?
regards
Mathan

Comment: you can access the files like all the others, when you use the file path. The options are for eclipse views only.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with Markus' solution as it works in the generic case.

An alternative, much simpler, approach is to make the file name begin with ".", by default all files with that prefix are hidden in Eclipse (e.g. the .project and .classpath files in every project).

Comment: As per your idea files will be hidden if it's name start with `.`, then can we call that file in browser ? I want to make one Java file that should be hidden and want to call in browser when I manually call it from address bar. Is it possible or not sir ?